# How to write a simple interpreter wrapper?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a couple of scripts for remote control of a server. Those scripts all need some environment variables set. My idea is to write a simple interpreter wrapper which first sets the variables and then calls the actual interpreter.

I tried as follows:

One of the scripts:

```
#! ../common/pywrapper.sh

import argparse
import parse_shell_vars
# ....and some more lines
```

The wrapper (`../common/pywrapper.sh` relative to the scripts):

```
#!/bin/bash

# echo params just to see what's going on
echo $@
# here would be some more configuration
python3.5 $@
```

Now, when I invoke the script, I get:

```
$ ./my_script.py param1 param2
./my_script.py: line 3: import: command not found
./my_script.py: line 4: import: command not found
```

**How can I properly create an "interpreter wrapper"?**

Remark: I know that I could export the variables in a previously-run configuration script or install them globally by some initialization script of the shell. But I think a wrapper is a good solution in this case, because I can start the scripts directly on any machine without previously installing something. Plus the scripts are self explaining for someone reading them. No guessing about required installation steps. All configuration and installation can be done by editing the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! ../common/pywrapper.sh

import argparse
```

You are mixing Python and shell. Use a Python interpreter in the shebang line for Python scripts.

Suggest doing this entirely in Python. Simpler and more portable to have one scripting language rather than several. You can get and modify environment variables with os.environ.

Comment: I see no reason why it should be impossible to write a script that acts as an interpreter by calling an actual interpreter.

Comment: My reading of execve(2) was inaccurate, you apparently can have another script as an interpreter.  By convention, these have the shebang line of the language they are written in, however.  And again, I prefer one scripting language and fewer wrappers, its simpler.